# How to disable the selection of an item when the first letter of the option is pressed in the Select component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material UI Select component and I'm trying to build a filter inside to display only the items that match the input entered by the user.

I build a minimal example of what I'm developing.

```js
function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("");
  const [filterExpression, setFilterExpression] = React.useState("");

  const onChangeSelection = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: unknown }>,
    child: React.ReactNode
  ) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toString();
    setSelectedOption(value);
  };

  const onChangeExpression = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toString();
    console.log(`value:`, value);
    setFilterExpression(value);
  };

  const stopImmediatePropagation = (e: any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select onChange={onChangeSelection} value={selectedOption}>
        <MenuItem
          dense
          divider
          value={""}
          onClickCapture={stopImmediatePropagation}
        >
          <TextField value={filterExpression} onChange={onChangeExpression} />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem dense key={"One"} value={"One"}>
          One
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem dense key={"Two"} value={"Two"}>
          Two
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem dense key={"Three"} value={"Three"}>
          Three
        </MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My problem now is that by default the select component allows the user to press any letter and if there is an option in which the first letter matches the user input, it selects that option.

So, if I have 3 options (`One`, `Two` and `Three`) and the user types `O` the select component will select the `One` option and the value of my text field won't change. However, if the user types `F` the text field will be updated to `F`.

I would like to disable this behavior, so, I have been trying to stop the propagation of events like `onKeyUpCapture`, `onChangeCapture`, `onKeyDownCapture` but I haven't' been able to avoid this.

Do you have any suggestions to fix it?
You can check the functional example here:

[image: Edit inspiring-ramanujan-sv25c]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The text focus navigation functionality is implemented in the `onKeyDown` of `MenuList` (I [implemented it](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blame/v4.5.1/packages/material-ui/src/MenuList/MenuList.js#L158) about 6 months ago). Stopping propagation of that event on the `MenuItem` (it would also work to stop propagation on the `TextField`) prevents the event from reaching `MenuList`.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("");
  const [filterExpression, setFilterExpression] = React.useState("");

  const onChangeSelection = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<{ name?: string | undefined; value: unknown }>,
    child: React.ReactNode
  ) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toString();
    setSelectedOption(value);
  };

  const onChangeExpression = (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const value = event.target.value.toString();
    console.log(`value:`, value);
    setFilterExpression(value);
  };

  const stopImmediatePropagation = (e: any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select onChange={onChangeSelection} value={selectedOption}>
        <MenuItem
          dense
          divider
          value={""}
          onClickCapture={stopImmediatePropagation}
          onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}
        >
          <TextField value={filterExpression} onChange={onChangeExpression} />
        </MenuItem>

        <MenuItem dense key={"One"} value={"One"}>
          One
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem dense key={"Two"} value={"Two"}>
          Two
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem dense key={"Three"} value={"Three"}>
          Three
        </MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Stop text focus navigation]

Comment: +1 @Ryan . This does the trick!!! I was stuck on this for last 4 hours. Material UI was so simple to use in earlier versions. But now its become a framework that's not useful for enterprise apps since every enterprise company have their own UX guys and they specify things that are not existing in Material UI. So at least for building libraries at enterprise level material ui is not perfect. It just consumes more tim than anticipated at time of requirement.

Comment: In case anyone else made this mistake… the `<TextField>` has to be wrapped in a `<MenuItem>` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue as well. I figured that to easily prevent the propagation on a specific Input you just need to add

```
 onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
```

On the input

```
                    <FormInput onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}/>
```

Hope this helps folks looking for a solution where you don't want to use MenuItem

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue many times but I found a best solution for it.

You can solve it by adding `stopPropagation` on your search input menu item -

```
<MenuItem onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}><input type="text" /></MenuItem>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).