# Disable "Select By Typing" in Material UI Menu Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a pop-up menu that has a couple different filters (buttons, selects, and text fields). I'm using the Material UI Menu component, but have run into an issue when trying to use the text fields. Because the Menu component is acting like a `<Select />`, when I type something in the text fields, it tries to select different MenuItems instead of staying focused on the text box.

So using the example found in the sandbox below, users wouldn't be able to type anything in the "search for a different food" textbox if it started with an "A", "B", or "C". If you wanted to type in "apricots", the menu would change focus from the textbox to the "Apples" MenuItem.

I don't see any props for this in the Menu API, so I'm curious to know if there is any work arounds, or even a different component that is more suited for this.

Thanks!

Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mccarthy-zy2b7

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Button, Menu, MenuItem, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

export default function App() {
  const [menu, setMenu] = useState(null);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={(e) => setMenu(e.currentTarget)}>
        Filters
      </Button>

      <Menu
        anchorEl={menu}
        open={Boolean(menu)}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: "bottom",
          horizontal: "left"
        }}
        onClose={() => setMenu(null)}
      >
        <MenuItem>Apples</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Bananas</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>Carrots</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem>
          <TextField
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
            variant={"outlined"}
            label={"search a different food..."}
          />
        </MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable the selection of an item when the first letter of the option is pressed in the Select component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378786/how-to-disable-the-selection-of-an-item-when-the-first-letter-of-the-option-is-p)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use e.stopPropagation() in the onKeyDown event for the MenuItem containing the TextField. This will prevent the key down event from propagating to the Menu component.

```js
    <MenuItem onKeyDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
        <TextField
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
            variant={"outlined"}
            label={"search a different food..."}
        />
    </MenuItem>
```

Reference: [How to disable the selection of an item when the first letter of the option is pressed in the Select component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378786/how-to-disable-the-selection-of-an-item-when-the-first-letter-of-the-option-is-p)