# TextField in MenuItem causes nextFocus.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uitextfield

I have created a `Menu` with Material UI that pops up when a button gets clicked. This `Menu` displays a dynamic list of id's that can get filtered with a `Textfield` positioned at the top of the Menu. But when I'm typing inside of the textfield I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: nextFocus.getAttribute is not a function`.
I have no Idea what could cause this issue and how it can be resolved.

[image]

This is the code of my `SearchableFilter` component that is shown on the image above. I have removed some unnecessry styling in the code

```js
const SearchableFilter = ({ values, label, setState, state }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false);
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  const openMenu = (event) => {
    setFocused(true);
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const selectItem = (value) => {
    handleClose();
    setState(value);
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setState("");
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    return setSearchValue(event.target.value);
  };

  const filteredValues = values.filter((value) =>
    value.includes(searchValue.trim())
  );

  const handleClose = () => {
    setFocused(false);
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.margin}>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={openMenu}
        disableRipple
        endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon color={state && "primary"} />}
      >
        {label}
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="menu-appbar"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        getContentAnchorEl={null}
        anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "left" }}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        elevation={2}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem
          button={false}
          dense={true}
          key="input"
          className={classes.menuItem}
        >
          <TextField
            id="input"
            label="Search"
            value={searchValue}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </MenuItem>
        <List style={{ maxHeight: "300px", overflow: "auto" }}>
          {filteredValues.map((value) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={value}
              dense={true}
              className={classes.menuItem}
              disableGutters={true}
              onClick={() => selectItem(value)}
            >
              {value}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### Full error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: nextFocus.getAttribute is not a function
    at moveFocus (MenuList.js:76)
    at handleKeyDown (MenuList.js:188)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:8299)
    at react-dom.development.js:8508
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22396)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3745)
    at dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:8507)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:6005)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:5924)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22413)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889)
```

### Edit:

Here is a CodeSandBox that displays the error:

[image: CodeSandBox link]

Comment: This is caused by the text navigation functionality in `Menu`. It's trying to move focus to a menu item with text matching what you're typing. Without having a running example to look over, I'm not sure how `nextFocus` ends up getting set to something without a `getAttribute` function, but you should be able to fix it in a similar way as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378786/how-to-disable-the-selection-of-an-item-when-the-first-letter-of-the-option-is-p/58379376#58379376.

Comment: I have added a link to a CodeSandBox which produces the error. And I will have a look at your linked answer.

Comment: Adding `onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}` to the `MenuItem` solves my issue.

Comment: As far as the cause of the error, it looks like a slight bug where the code is [using `list.firstChild`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.5/packages/material-ui/src/MenuList/MenuList.js#L17) when it should be using `list.firstElementChild`. It ends up setting `nextFocus` to a whitespace text node in your case rather than the first menu item and text nodes don't have a `getAttribute` function. When I have some free time in a few weeks, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by @Ryan Cogswell in the comments.

Adding the `onKeyDown` prop to the parent `MenuItem` of the `TextField` fixed my issue.

```
<MenuItem
  button={false}
  onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}
>
  <TextField
    onChange={handleChange}
   value={value}
  />
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

As answere by JonasLevin.

If you have any div or other element wrapping Textfield , you should add
onKeyDown={e => e.stopPropagation()}
to that element

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31868219)