# Material UI Checkbox auto focus on typing input field Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, material-ui

can someone please help me with this prob?
Here is the codesandbox, I follow the demo from document Tags with multiple checkbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectcheckmarks-material-demo-forked-ecbdu?file=/demo.js
all I did were to add an input field to it, but when I typed any Letters that matched the label field, Its immediately jump to that checkbox and can not type that letter, can anyone please help me with this issue? , thank you really much
[image]

for example , I typed "K"

[image]

It somehow will focus in Kelly Snyder Option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh nvm after researching it for hours I found the solution refer to this:

[How to disable the selection of an item when the first letter of the option is pressed in the Select component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378786/how-to-disable-the-selection-of-an-item-when-the-first-letter-of-the-option-is-p)

Linksandbox :https://codesandbox.io/s/stop-text-focus-navigation-85o2p?fontsize=14

if anyone got the same issue