# How to disable MUI Select "picking" the menu items when I type the first alphabet

Tags: material-ui

I'm using the MUI Select component to make a dropdown list.  I want to be able to:

1. use the mouse to select the item
2. use the up/down key to move and press to select

but I want to **disable selecting the item by typing the initial character**.

eg. if I have the list

```
Apple
Apricot
Banana
Mango
Mangosteen
```

If I press `A`, it will select `Apple`.  If I press `A` again, it will select `Apricot`.  I want to disable this and only select by keyboard or mouse scrolling.  How do I do that ?  Thanks.

PS: More info.  In the children of the Select, I have a `search box` at the top of the menu list.  The requirement is for this `search box` to filter the menu item.  When I type inside the `search box`, if the character pressed is not the starting character of the label of the menu items, the `search box` will do the filtering correctly.  But when I type a character that is the starting of the menu item, it will jump to the list instead of doing the filtering.  Is there any way to prevent the keypress inside the `search box` from triggering the menu items to be selected ?

[image]

I understand that AutoComplete has this ability to type in search but the requirement is to have a `search box`.  How to implement this `search box` ? Thanks & Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this post: [How to disable the selection of an item when the first letter of the option is pressed in the Select component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58378786/how-to-disable-the-selection-of-an-item-when-the-first-letter-of-the-option-is-p)

you need to stop propagation on the `MenuItem` or the `TextField` you are using as the search box.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Very grateful.  I was trying to disable the list which worked earlier, but I have a lot of error in the console because the selected item is not found in the list (being disabled).  This works exactly to stop the propagation of the keystroke.  Thanks again.